# How do you use pyautogui to scroll to the top of a page?

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I can use something like this:

```
pyautogui.scroll(200)
```

with a large number to scroll to the top, however I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: some programs allow “end” character to scroll to top. did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what program you're using to scroll. But in many programs `ctl+home` jumps to the top of a document/window and `ctl+end` jumps to the end of a document/window.

```
import pyautogui

# click somewhere in the window to activate the window
# change x, y for your configuration
pyautogui.click(x=100, y=200)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'home')
```

Comment: I was using Chrome.. That worked thnx.